# CakePHP Upgrade console does no changes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to upgrade my CakePHP 2 project to CakePHP 3. For this purpose I am using the CakePHP upgrade console. After installing it as described on [the upgrade tool page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html), I run

```
./bin/cake upgrade all ../admin/app --verbose
```

which prints out

```
Welcome to CakePHP v3.1.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /Users/Ivan/Sites/baslernachhilfe/web/tmp/upgrade/src/
PHP : 5.6.10
---------------------------------------------------------------
*** Upgrade step Locations ***
*** Upgrade step Namespaces ***
*** Upgrade step AppUses ***
*** Upgrade step RenameClasses ***
*** Upgrade step RenameCollections ***
*** Upgrade step MethodNames ***
*** Upgrade step MethodSignatures ***
*** Upgrade step Fixtures ***
*** Upgrade step Tests ***
*** Upgrade step I18n ***
*** Upgrade step PrefixedTemplates ***
```

However, no changes are performed. Nothing is moved around, nothing is added to the files. What could the problem be? Running OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the code, I realised the following: I had put the upgrade folder in a subfolder called "tmp". The code for upgrading, however, filters for all paths containing "tmp" and therefore did not process any task.

Comment: Note that the upgrade tools is a standalone application, it should be installed in a seaprate folder, _outside_ of the application that you are trying to upgrade! (from [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html#installation): "_The upgrade tool is installed as a standalone application_")